# Yet another ASP:Textbox vs <input type="text">

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have read through some articles on this topic but I am still cautious about this. I am all along using ASP:Textbox but I would like to know what are the things an input textbox cannot possibly perform without using a ASP:Textbox or takes much more effort to pull off?

I have a Jquery tooltip sample which uses HTML input textbox and I am not sure if I should change all my ASP:Textboxes to HTML textboxes, the things which I need to perform on this textboxes are RequiredFieldValidation as well as storing their values into the database.

Anyone can advice me on this rookie question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know there is no visible server side programming difference between a HTML input box and an ASP Textbox. ASP.NET Validators would work perfectly both ways.

As for your tooltip concern. Jquery doesn't care if your using an ASP Textbox since your ASP textbox will end up as an HTML textbox anyways.

And for the advice - i don't recommend you changing all your ASP Textbox to HTML input boxes, its just a waste of time. You should use the CSSClass / class property to display the tooltip instead. That way it would work on your regular HTML input box and ASP Textboxes + other page elements.

Answer (score 3):

The asp.net textbox IS a html input box from jQuerys point of view. Everything special about it is done on the server (including viewstate validation). The question you need to ask, is what value does giving it a server side reference bring to your app?  Generally the answer is easy server side reference, but does that apply in your case?