# Is it considered bad practice if you use an <input> for a textbox compared to <asp:Textbox>?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET page that contains a form and a button. In order to use the `OnKeyPress` and a javascript function (to stop the user from using the enter key and without adding a `FilteredTextBoxExtender`) attribute I had to change the `<asp:Textbox>` to an `<input>` with `type="text"`.

Is this considered bad practice? Or are there valid situtations where  should be used?

To ensure this question isn't subjective - are there any other ways to prevent the user using the enter key when typing in an ASP.NET textbox? (without putting code in the code behind)

Comment: Why not simply add the OnKeyPress to the textbox?

Comment: Please have a look on following link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682734/yet-another-asptextbox-vs-input-type-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add JavaScript to `<asp:TextBox />`. You can either attach the JavaScript using the ClientID of the control, or you can add it in the codebehind using

> MyTextBox.Attributes.Add("onKeyPress", "myJavaScriptFunction()");

Answer (score 3):

In General you should use Asp.Net control only when is strictly required ad the classic HTML are much faster as they don't need any server elaboration to be rendered

Answer (score 3):

If you want your input to be accessed by .NET code-behind then it's considered best practice to use the TextBox control. You can put a runat=server on an input, but only when you must.

If it were me, I'd use the , add an ID and set the ClientIDMode="Static" if possible, or add a class with CssClass="class", then use jQuery to handle the onKeyPress even with something like this:

```
$('.class').on('change', function() {

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to change the control type in order to use client side events in javascript.

The control has a `ClientId` property that can be used for binding the event to (using `getElementById`, for example).

Answer (score 1):

You should just use the ClientID of your asp:TextBox
here is an example using jQuery :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="inputTB" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $('#<%=inputTB.ClientID%>').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) // return key
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```